# Do iMacros support javascript or any other script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, scripting, imacros

There is a webpage which is having one textbox for every day.I am using iMacros firefox plugin to fill all textboxes.  As of now, my macro fills all textboxes from monday to friday with a desired value, and then it submits the page. The webpage is designed like, if it is not friday today then it displays the error and will not let you submit. But if somehow i could get what day is today and then somehow fill the text box of only that day and submit the page then it will work. I think this can be done if iMacros support javascript or any other scripting language.

So first thing do it supports any scripting language at all? If yes then please help me how to do this, or please share any tutorial for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, iMacros can run javascript in Firefox. If the javascript file is in the macros folder you are going to see it listed in the macros list and can run it directly in the browser by double clicking.

This javascript running in iMacros is somehow different, because it supports calls to the iMacros macro player through iimPlay(). Have a look at [this link](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface) and also the samples installed with the iMacros Addon.

There is also an active [iMacros user forum](http://forum.iopus.com/) where you find several tips around iMacros.

Regards,

Marcia

Answer (score 0):

It goes beyond just javascript, you can use jQuery even node.js. Just take a look at the imacros forum.